# Use CSS selectors to selectively style list

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have an element that can contain multiple unordered lists.

I want to selectivly style the separators - that is the separators that divide LI elements and separators that divide UL elements. Here's some HTML:

What I'm effectively trying to achieve is:

1. Everything is separated either by UL separator or LI separator
2. If it's the last UL, no UL separator but last LI has a separator
3. If it's not the last UL - the last LI has no separator

---

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li></li><!-- has blue bottom border -->
        <li></li><!-- has blue bottom border -->
        <li></li><!-- HAS NO BOTTOM BORDER -->
    </ul><!-- has green bottom border -->
    <ul>
        <li></li><!-- has blue bottom border -->
        <li></li><!-- has blue bottom border -->
        <li></li><!-- has blue bottom border -->
    </ul><!-- HAS NO BOTTOM BORDER -->
</div>
```

I've come up with this code - which works but the last LI of the last UL dows not have a separator.

```
.nav-blue ul
{
    border-bottom:solid 0.5rem Green;
}

.nav-blue ul:last-child
{
    border-bottom:0;
}

.nav-blue li
{
    border-bottom:solid 0.1rem Blue;
}

.nav-blue li:last-child
{
    border-bottom:0;
}

/* This does not work */
.nav-blue not(ul:last-child) li:last-child
{
    border-bottom:solid 0.1rem Blue;
}
```

There may be also be prettier ways of achieving this and I'm keen for help and further advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you not apply classes to the `ul` or `li` elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `:not` pseudoselector (in your example you forgot the `:`) you can write like so

```
/* 1 */ div li { 
            border-bottom: 1px blue solid; 
        }

/* 2 */ div ul:not(:last-child) { 
            border-bottom: 1px green solid; 
        }

/* 3 */ div ul:not(:last-child) li:last-child { 
            border-bottom: 0; 
        }
```

Basically with these rules the border

1. is always set on `li` *(blue)*
2. is always set on `ul` *(green)* except  when it is the `last-child`
3. is removed on every `li:last-child` except when it belongs to the last `ul`

Answer (score 1):

try this : http://jsfiddle.net/zj9v81t7/19/

and css code :

```
ul , li{margin:0; padding:0}
div ul
{
    border-bottom:1px solid Green;
    padding-bottom:10px; margin-bottom:10px;

}
div ul li
{
    border-bottom:1px solid blue;
}
div ul li:last-child{
    border-bottom:0;
}

div ul:last-child
{
    border-bottom:0;
}

div ul:last-child li
{
    border-bottom:1px solid blue;
}
```